# MySQL: Limiting number of results received based on a column value | Combining queries

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I've done research on this problem, but am having trouble finding a solution.

I have the following query that gives me a list of "some_id"s:

```
SELECT some_id FROM example GROUP BY some_id
```

And I have the following query that will get a list of the 5 most recent entries for a row that has "some_id" equal to a number.

```
SELECT * FROM example
WHERE some_id = 1
ORDER BY last_modified DESC
LIMIT 5
```

How can I get the the top 5 most recent entries from the table "example" for each "some_id", using only one query?  If there are less than 5 entries for a "some_id", it is okay to include them, if that makes things less complex.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found the answer when looking at the first answer in the following post:

[How do I limit the number of rows per field value in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421807/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-per-field-value-in-sql)

I've modified it to fit my specific needs:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *, @num := if(@some_id = some_id, @num := @num + 1, 1) as row_num,
           @some_id := some_id as some_id
    FROM example
    ORDER BY last_modified DESC
) as e
WHERE row_num <= 5
```

Comment: I found I had to add initialization of the variables: `SELECT ... FROM example, (SELECT @some_id:=0, @num:=0) as init ...`

Comment: You had to mention that this approach doesn't work without `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: absolutely agree witth @Green, `ORDER BY` is required

Answer (score -4):

Hi Please use `Group by` and  `having clause` for check limit for every id..

```
SELECT * FROM `example`
GROUP BY some_id
HAVING count( * ) <= 5
ORDER BY last_modified DESC
```

It will check for every `some_id` and check if `number of rows for some_id is <=5` then it will be display result.