# MySQL query with session (@variables) working in MySQL Workbench, but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Been wrestling with a version of this question for a few hours, and I know that it is probably something little that I'm missing.

I have a query based off of the first answer in this post:

[How do I limit the number of rows per field value in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421807/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-per-field-value-in-sql)

Which does exactly what I want it to do in MySQL Workbench, but does not ever set the session variable to '2' when run from:

```
mysql_query()
```

in PHP.

The following is a table, 'mytab' that demonstrates the problem:

```
+----+--------------+---------------+
| id | first_column | second_column |
+----+--------------+---------------+
|  1 |            1 |             1 |
|  2 |            1 |             4 |
|  3 |            2 |            10 |
|  4 |            3 |             4 |
|  5 |            1 |             4 |
|  6 |            2 |             5 |
|  7 |            1 |             6 |
+----+--------------+---------------+
```

And a simplified query:

```
select
    id, first_column, second_column, row_num
from 
(
    select *,
    @num := if(@first_column = first_column, 2, 1) as row_num,
    @first_column := first_column as c
    from mytab order by first_column,id
) as t
having row_num <= 1;
```

From MySQL workbench I get this:

```
+----+--------------+---------------+---------+
| id | first_column | second_column | row_num |
+----+--------------+---------------+---------+ 
|  1 |            1 |             1 |       1 |
|  3 |            2 |            10 |       1 |
|  4 |            3 |             4 |       1 |
+----+--------------+---------------+---------+
```

And from PHP I get this:

```
+----+--------------+---------------+---------+
| id | first_column | second_column | row_num |
+----+--------------+---------------+---------+
|  1 |            1 |             1 |       1 |
|  2 |            1 |             4 |       1 |
|  3 |            2 |            10 |       1 |
|  4 |            3 |             4 |       1 |
|  5 |            1 |             4 |       1 |
|  6 |            2 |             5 |       1 |
|  7 |            1 |             6 |       1 |
+----+--------------+---------------+---------+
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Many thanks!

---

**EDIT:** Here is my pared-down PHP code, since the problem in reality is tied in to some more complex stuff.

```
class sql_helper extends other
{
    public function query_handler($sql, $error_message) 
    {
        $this->connect(); // Not shown, but works without issue

        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die($error_message.''.mysql_error());

        return $result;
    }

    public static function sql_result_to_assoc($sql_result) 
    {
        $result_array = array();

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result))
            $result_array[] = $row;

        return $result_array;
    }

    public function sql_to_assoc($sql, $error_message)
    {
        $result = $this->query_handler($sql, $error_message);

        return $this->sql_result_to_assoc($result);
    }
}

$sql = "
    select
    id, first_column, second_column, row_num
    from 
    (
        select *,
        @num := if(@first_column = first_column, 2, 1) as row_num,
        @first_column := first_column as c
        from mytab order by first_column,id
    ) as t
    having row_num<=1";

$sql_helper   = new sql_helper();
$result_array = $sql_helper->sql_to_assoc($sql, '');
```

Comment: "Am I doing something wrong?" Yes. Please post your PHP code.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: Thank you.  This particular query actually only needs to store the session variable for the duration of the query, so there should be no worries about browser requests.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the session variables:

```
SET @num:=0;
SET @first_column:=0;
```

This must be done in the same MySQL session and before your query.

Answer (score 1):

As Jerahian answered, they need to be in the same session.  I have typically done inline declarations but you have to wrap as if it was a select and assign an "alias" such as

```
select
    id, first_column, second_column, row_num
from 
   ( select *,
           @num := if(@first_column = first_column, 2, 1) as row_num,
           @first_column := first_column as c
        from 
           mytab,
           ( select @first_column := 0 ) as Sqlvars
      order by 
           first_column,
           id
   ) as t
having 
   row_num <= 1;
```

Notice the very subtle initialization of @first_column := 0 as "sqlvars" alias... Then it can be used as you are intending.  And if you have multiple variables, just comma separate as you would other columns... such as

```
   ( select @first_column := 0, 
            @someOtherField := '2013-06-02',
            @someString := 'testing' ) as Sqlvars
```