# Mysql select rows with limit to different column

Tags: mysql

The structure of table goes as bellow

```
Posts (
   id int, 
   category_id int, 
   popularity int, 
)
```

I wanna select 5 categories each having 5 rows.

Like Select * from posts where category_id in ("1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5") limit 5 -- limit each category_id by selection of 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNION to connect multiple select statements to show one combined result.
It is probably the easiest way to solve your problem.

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts where category_id=1 limit 5
UNION 
SELECT * FROM posts where category_id=2 limit 5
UNION 
SELECT * FROM posts where category_id=3 limit 5
UNION 
SELECT * FROM posts where category_id=4 limit 5
UNION 
SELECT * FROM posts where category_id=5 limit 5
```

The same question has already been asked:
[MySQL: Limiting number of results received based on a column value | Combining queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353436/mysql-limiting-number-of-results-received-based-on-a-column-value-combining-q)
It provides a more sophisticated solution.

Comment: is that an efficient way to do when dealing with thousands of rows. Table was for example

Comment: No,
With so many rows, you could write a stored procedure that creates a table for you with the desired output.The Procedure could still consist of "simple" SQL. If you want to solve it with one query, have a look at the question i linked in my answer